# Как в OpenCL изменить яркость пикселя?

Tags: opencv, opencl

Задача написать программу, которая будет изменять яркость для каждого пикселя картинки.
Само по себе изменение яркости кажется несложным, проблема непосредственно с самим OpenCL.
Код ниже по задумке должен преобразовать каждый пиксель в RGB цвет (123,123,123).
Код:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/ocl.hpp>

int main() {
    // Включаем использование OpenCL в OpenCV
    cv::ocl::setUseOpenCL(true);

    // Загружаем изображение
    cv::Mat image = cv::imread("/home/marat/Desktop/white-opencl/h.jpg");
    //cv::imshow("abc", image);
    //cv::waitKey();

    // Проверяем, удалось ли загрузить изображение
    if (image.empty()) {
        std::cout << "Не удалось загрузить изображение" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Создаем контекст OpenCL
    cv::ocl::Context context;
    if (!context.create(cv::ocl::Device::TYPE_GPU)) {
        std::cout << "Не удалось создать контекст OpenCL" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Создаем объект управления очередью выполнения OpenCL
    cv::ocl::Queue queue = cv::ocl::Queue(context, context.device(0));

    // Создаем объект управления памятью OpenCL для изображения
    cv::UMat uimage = image.getUMat(cv::ACCESS_READ, cv::USAGE_ALLOCATE_DEVICE_MEMORY);

    // Создаем OpenCL ядро для преобразования пикселей
    std::string kernelSource = R"(
    __kernel void white_pixels(__global uchar3* image) {
    int x = get_global_id(0);
    int y = get_global_id(1);

    int index = y * get_global_size(0) + x;

    image[index].x = 123;
    image[index].y = 123;
    image[index].z = 123;
}
)";
    cv::ocl::ProgramSource programSource(kernelSource);
    cv::String errmsg;
    //cv::String buildopt = cv::format("-D dstT=%s", cv::ocl::typeToStr(umat_dst.depth())); // "-D dstT=float"
    cv::String buildopt = "";
    cv::ocl::Program program = context.getProg(programSource, buildopt, errmsg);

    cv::ocl::Kernel kernel("white_pixels", program);

    // Устанавливаем аргументы ядра
    kernel.set(0,uimage);
    //kernel.args(cv::ocl::KernelArg::ReadWrite(uimage));

    // Запускаем ядро на устройстве OpenCL
    size_t globalSize[2] = {image.cols, image.rows};
    if (!kernel.run(2, globalSize, nullptr, false)) {
        std::cout << "Ошибка выполнения ядра OpenCL" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Копируем результат обратно в память хоста
    //image = uimage.getMat(cv::ACCESS_READ);
    uimage.copyTo(image);

    // Отображаем результат
    cv::imshow("The result", image);
    cv::waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```